# Get the first word from the string

Tags: c#

I would like to get only the first word of the string regardless of any character or punctuation in front of it.

Sometimes, there could be `,` or `.` or `!`. I don't want these characters.

```
var s = "Hello, World";
var firstWord = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(" "));
```

This gives me `Hello,`. I would like to get `Hello` only.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you accept regex expression?

Comment: Sure but I don't know how to use it :)

Comment: If unfamiliar with regex try `Split`

Comment: I would first use Replace() to remove any punctuation/characters you don't want to consider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work for you. I assumed that words will be separated with whitespace.

```
var input = "Hello, World";
var output = Regex.Replace(input.Split()[0], @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\ ]+", "");
```

Comment: @MahadevanSwamy you are welcome. Please mark as an answer so it can be useful to others as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Careful. This won't work with something like "Let's go to the mall". The first word would be "Lets" because the regex replace is stripping all non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 13):

Simply use the following regex:

```
var s = "Hello, World";
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"^([\w\-]+)");
Console.WriteLine(result.Value); // Result is "Hello"
```

This will get the first word regardless of whether or not it ends with punctuation or simply precedes a space.

Comment: result.value will be the word.

Comment: @GaurangDave Right. `Console.WriteLine(result)` printed out "Hello" because of `Match`'s `ToString()` implementation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

LATE ENTRY:
If you don't want to use Regular Expressions:

```
    private string GetFirstWord(string text)
    {
        var candidate = text.Trim();
        if (!candidate.Any(Char.IsWhiteSpace))
            return text;

        return candidate.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOfAny` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/11w09h50(v=vs.110).aspx) is an alternative if you know the list of characters you want to use. It really depends on the definition you want to use and which characters you want to handle. How do you want to handle characters like œ,é,µ,½,¶,ç,+,-,3...?

Also, do you want to handle locale as some characters might have a classification that is dependant on the language.

`Char` has many function that allows you to classify characters. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx.

And there is also the regex solutions proposed by others.

So the best solution really depends on your need. Do you need to properly handle any Unicode characters or only some specific ASCII characters?

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case where there is only one word (no separator characters) - index will be -1.