# First Word of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

How do I get the first word of a string.

```
string test = "hello, world"
```

I used `test.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault()` but it returns "`hello,`"

I could try by adding the separator as comma but even if there is comma or space, I need just the word 'hello'. I mean if string test = "hello world" then also it should return "hello"

Comment: [Split(Char\[\], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) (multiple separators)

Comment: firstWord = test.Split(' ', ',').FirstOrDefault(); This worked for me

Comment: @StackUser Think about all the overhead of splitting all words into an array, or the overhead of using a RegEx! How many other chars do you expect beside a comma? `test.Substring(0,test.IndexOf(" ")).Trim(",");` or simply a `test.Substring(0,test.IndexOf(" "))` with a loop to trim non-alphanumeric characters: `Char.IsLetter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first word from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868766/get-the-first-word-from-the-string)

Answer (score 2):

Regex is the way !!!

Try following code:

```
string pattern = @"^\w+";
string test = "hello, world";
var firstWord = Regex.Match(test, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(firstWord);

// output
// hello
```

Don't forget to include namespace '**System.Text.RegularExpressions**'

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to have the A-Z or a-z letters in the string, use regex to remove everything else, then split the string.

```
Regex.Replace(str.Trim(), "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ").Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you could use something like the Char class, it's easier to undertsand.

for example:

```
string test = "Hello, world!";

string split = test.Split(' ')[0];           //Split by space
if (!Char.IsLetter(split.Last()))            //Check if last character is letter
    split = split.Remove(split.Length - 1);  //If not, remove last character
    
Console.WriteLine(split);                    //Print out the word
```

Comment: What about `string test = "Hello!?! world!";`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, he asked about "Hello, world", but you are right :)